# Concordion: How to compare two files?

Tags: concordion

I am new to Concordion. I have created a sample project and trying to compare two files with the help of concordion.Kinldy let me know Do we have any tag in concordion which can compare two files?

Answer (score 1):

My solution.

**In your HTML file :**

```
<span concordion:set="#urlFileA">/path/fileA.json</span>
<span concordion:set="#urlFileB">/path/fileB.json</span>

<span concordion:assertTrue="compareTo(#urlFileA,#urlFileB)">true</span>
```

**In your fixture :**

```
public boolean compareTo(String urlFileA,String urlFileB){

// Get both file with File and FileInputStream to read files
// Compare .....
// Then return true or false 

}
```